# Unhandled Exception: invalid parameter was passed to a service or function But only after the program has completed

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

As per an assignment, I've made a child class(`PioneerWorld`) that inherits publicly from `PioneerAm` which inherits from `PioneerCarRadio`, which inherits from the base class `CarRadio`.

I've then called a function that new the appropriate class object and returns the pointer to a `PioneerCarRadio * pRadio` pointer.

The program then loops and the user can then choose to change the radio between `PioneerCarRadio`, `PioneerAm`, or `PioneerWorld`. Choosing a different radio deletes the previous object in `pRadio` and news the appropriate radio with the previously mentioned function.

The problem that occurs is that at **any time after** I choose to switch to `PioneerWorld` and then exit the program, the Unhandled exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7765806C (ntdll.dll) in A-06.exe: 0xC000000D:
>   An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function. occurred

will occur after the `return 0` for the main. *Even if* the program is exiting when *not on the PioneerWorld radio*.

It doesn't do this for any of the other radios only when PioneerWorld is chosen at any time during the program will this occur.

From what I can tell the problem resides in the `PioneerWorld.h` file.

I have tried to add every single kind of exception catch in the try block (granted I don't believe I have a firm knowledge of how the try-catch exception handling works) but none have fixed the problem.

I have run it in debug mode and everything runs smoothly until:

```
   printf("\nGoodbye!\n");
   return 0;
}  **<-- HERE**
```

I have tried to place the PioneerWorld higher up on the inheritance hierarchy (eg. rather than

> *CarRadio-> PioneerCarRadio-> **PioneerAm-> PioneerWorld***

I changed it to

> *CarRadio-> PioneerCarRadio-> **PioneerWorld-> PioneerAm***

And the same problem still occurs. 
(Exiting anytime after pRadio has been switched to PioneerWorld radio causes the error but the *error does not occur if the radio was **never** switched to PioneerWorld*)

I am honestly at a loss. ;_;

Main:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <new.h>
#include <exception>
#include <conio.h>
#include "PioneerWorld.h"
#include <iostream>
#pragma warning(disable :4996)
using namespace std;

//Prototype
PioneerCarRadio * createRadio(char *s);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    //Variables
    PioneerCarRadio * pRadio = NULL;
    char *arg = argv[argc - 1];
    char previousArg[8] = "";
    char selection = 0;

    //Loops the main process
    do
    {
        //Checks if the previous argument is the same as the current, if not then create a new radio
        if (strcmp(previousArg, arg) != 0)
        {
            //Creates the radio and reads any exceptions thrown
            try
            {
                pRadio = createRadio(arg);
                strcpy(previousArg, arg);
            }
            catch (char* e)     //If argument is not present or invalid, exception is caught here
            {
                printf("\n EXCEPTION: Invalid switch modifier.\n");
                return -1;
            }
            catch (bad_alloc& ba)   //If no memory can be allocated in the instantiation of the radio, exception is caught here
            {
                printf("\n EXCEPTION: Cannot allocate memory.\n");
                return -2;
            }
            catch (bad_exception& e)            //Catch exceptions for unknown errors
            {
                printf("\n EXCEPTION: Unknown Excpetion Error.\n");
                return -3;
            }
            catch (runtime_error& re)
            {
                printf("\n EXCEPTION: Runtime error\n");
                return -4;
            }
        }

        //Shows the currents settings for radio
        pRadio->ShowCurrentSettings();

        //Gets the user inputed selection
        selection = pRadio->GetInput();

        //Make the selection setting change (if appilicable)
        pRadio->MakeSelection(selection);

        //Redisplay the settings in case they had been adjusted
        pRadio->ShowCurrentSettings();

        //Checks what selection was made and changes the argument to the appropriate syntax
        if (selection == 'c')
        {
            strcpy(arg, "-car");
        }
        else if (selection == 'a')
        {
            strcpy(arg, "-am");
        }
        else if (selection == 'w')
        {
            strcpy(arg, "-world");
        }

        //Checks if the previous argument is the same as the current, if not then delete the current object
        if (strcmp(previousArg, arg) != 0 || selection == 'x')
        {
            //Deletes the current object 
            try
            {
                delete pRadio;
            }
            catch (bad_exception& e)        //Catches any unexpected exceptions
            {
                printf("\n EXCEPTION: Unknown Exception\n");
                return -5;
            }
            catch (runtime_error& re)
            {
                printf("\n EXCEPTION: Runtime error\n");
                return -6;
            }
        }


    } while (selection != 'x');     //Exits when user selects 'x'

    printf("\nGoodbye!\n");
    return 0;
}

PioneerCarRadio * createRadio(char *s)
{
    //Variables
    PioneerCarRadio * returnPtr = NULL;

    //Check if the parameter is there and valid
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        throw s;    //throw the parameter
    }
    else if (strcmp(s, "-car") == 0)
    {
        //News the PioneerCarRadio and throws the pointer if NULL
        if ((returnPtr = new PioneerCarRadio(false)) == NULL)
        {
            throw returnPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            return returnPtr;
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp(s, "-am") == 0)
    {
        //News the PioneerAM and throws the pointer if NULL
        if ((returnPtr = new PioneerAM(false)) == NULL)
        {
            throw returnPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            return returnPtr;
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp(s, "-world") == 0)
    {
        //News the PioneerWorld and throws the pointer if NULL
        if ((returnPtr = new PioneerWorld(false)) == NULL)
        {
            throw returnPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            return returnPtr;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw s;
    }

    return NULL;    //Default return

}
```

Problem Child (`PioneerWorld.h` file):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include"PioneerAM.h"


//Class
class PioneerWorld : public PioneerAM
{
private:

public:
    PioneerWorld(bool power, char *name = (char *)"Pioneer XS440-WLRD") : PioneerAM(power, name)
    {
        ChangeCurrentStation(531);
    }

    virtual ~PioneerWorld()
    {
        printf("Destroying Pioneer XS440-WRLD Radio.\n");
    }

    virtual void ScanUp()
    {
        Freqs storedAM = GetStoredFreqs();

        //if current_station is 1700, the current_station becomes 530
        if (GetCurrentStation() >= 1602)
        {
            ChangeCurrentStation(531);
            storedAM.AMFreq = GetCurrentStation();
        }
        else
        {
            ChangeCurrentStation(GetCurrentStation() + 9);
            storedAM.AMFreq = GetCurrentStation();
        }
    }

    virtual void ScanDown()
    {
        Freqs storedAM = GetStoredFreqs();

        //if current_station is 1700, the current_station becomes 530
        if (GetCurrentStation() <= 531)
        {
            ChangeCurrentStation(1602);
            storedAM.AMFreq = GetCurrentStation();
        }
        else
        {
            ChangeCurrentStation(GetCurrentStation() - 9);
            storedAM.AMFreq = GetCurrentStation();
        }
    }
};
```

The program should run until it is terminated without error and catch any exceptions, but instead if exiting the program at any time after radio was switched to PioneerWorld radio the program will execute normally until the main's return 0; at which point, on the next line (the '}') visual studios comes up with a error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7765806C (ntdll.dll) in A-06.exe: 0xC000000D:
>   An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function. occurred

This is my first post so if there's anything wrong or you'd like more of the code to better understand what is the problem just ask.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using threading anywhere? I've had this happen before in multithreaded environments when threads were detached rather than joined and the living ones tried to access a now-destroyed object.

Comment: Piece of advice : don't use virtual on definitions of overriding virtual functions in a derived class unless you want to declare a new signature (you may accidentally create a new totally different function if the signature does not  match an earlier virtual declaration) ,instead use override which will trigger an error if the base class(es) doesn't have a virtual function of the same signature.

Comment: IMHO Because I can only see dynamically allocated objects in your code ,your error most likely is caused by the destruction of a static member variable of some base class (which definitions you didn't supply).

Comment: No, I haven't used threading and I don't have any static variables in my base classes. And thanks for the advice, I'll fix that right now.

Comment: Another possible cause of that error might be the result of undefined behaviour from overwriting parts of memory through an wrong address or of incorrect size.